# Connect MSSQL (2017) DB with PHP7.4(x64) hosted in IIS

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm trying to connect the MSSQL(2017) DB with PHP7.4 (x64) hosted in IIS.
I have installed the SQL Drivers for PHP7.4 and placed the extension files NTS.DLL in ext.
I have the latest  ODBC Driver 17 installed. Still, I'm not able to connect to Database using Domain Account.
Server Authentication is set to "SQL Server & Windows Authentication mode" in SSMS for the DB.
Below is the error,

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 [1] => 18456 [code] => 18456 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'domain\user'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'domain\user'. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 [1] => 18456 [code] => 18456 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'domain\user'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'domain\user'. ) )

Below is the php code,

```php
<?php    
$servername = "DBservername";   
$uid = "domain\user"; 
$pwd = 'password';
$databasename = "DBName"; 
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=> $databasename, "UID"=> $uid, "PWD"=> $pwd );   
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $servername, $connectionInfo ); 
if( $conn )
{
    echo "Connection success";
}
else
{
      die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) ); 
} 

sqlsrv_close( $conn );    
?>
```

Comment: Your error suggests that you are using a trusted connection, due to `Login failed for user 'domain\user'`, however, your PHP suggests you are using SQL Authentication, as you declare a Username and Password. You aren't trying to pass AD credentials as a SQL Login, are you? If you are, that won't work. YOu either need to use a trusted connection and connect with a domain login ***or*** use SQL Authentication by passing a Login and password. They are 2 completely different authentication methods.

Comment: Thank You Larnu for the quick response, I do not have the SQL Login. Could you pls let me know what I need to change in the code,  how to pass the trusted connection in my code. I'm new to PHP and MSSQL,

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php) shows you exactly how to use `sqlsrv_connect`, including Windows Authentication. Documentation should always be your first port of call, it's what it's there for.

Comment: I followed it and tried without passing the username & password too. same error, Login failed for user 'domain\servername$

Comment: That suggests that the Domain account PHP/IIS is running under doesn't have access to the instance then. Checking the SQL Server logs will tell you the true error.